# Proper run-time construction pattern for large number of objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

What is the best way to create derived objects at run-time while adhering to LSP and always keeping the objects in a valid state.

I'm fairly new to construction patterns such as Factory and Builder and most of the examples I find are very simplistic. Here is my scenario:

I have one base class (some things left out for brevity):

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set ... null guard; }
    public string Property2 { get; set ... conditional null guard; }

    public virtual bool RequiresProperty2 => false;

    protected BaseClass(string property1)
    {
        null guard
        Property1 = property1;
    }
}
```

I have 50+ derived classes. Some of which require prop2 some of which don't. The ones that require prop2 have a constructor that forces prop2 to be passed in, enforcing that all BaseClass derived objects are in a valid state upon construction. I'm also trying to adhere to LSP and I'm using Castle Windsor for dependency injection.

The solution I've come up with is to create a factory that returns a builder:

```
public interface IFactory
{
    IBuilder Create(string type);
}

public interface IBuilder
{
    IBuilder SetProperty1(string property);
    IBuilder SetProperty2(string property);
    BaseClass Build();
}
```

The concrete implementation of the factory loads all the types that inherit from BaseClass through reflection. When you call Factory.Create(...) you pass it a string which is the string name of the type you want to create. Then the factory creates a builder passing the appropriate Type to the builder's constructor. The builder looks like so:

```
public sealed class ConcreteBuilder : IBuilder
{
    private static Type ClassType = typeof(BaseClass);

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate> 
        ClassConstructors = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    private readonly Type type;

    private string property1;
    private string property2;

    public ConcreteBuilder(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        if (!type.IsSubclassOf(ClassType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Must derive from BaseClass.");
        }

        this.type = type;
    }

    public IBuilder SetProperty1(string property)
    {
        this.property1 = property;
        return this;
    }

    public IBuilder SetProperty2(string property)
    {
        this.property2 = property;
        return this;
    }

    public BaseClass Build()
    {
        var arguments = BuildArguments();

        Delegate ctor;
        if (ClassConstructors.TryGetValue(this.type, out ctor))
        {
            return (BaseClass)ctor.DynamicInvoke(arguments);
        }

        return (BaseClass)GetConstructor(arguments).DynamicInvoke(arguments);
    }

    private object[] BuildArguments()
    {
        var args = new List<object>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.property1))
        {
            args.Add(this.property1);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.property2))
        {
            args.Add(this.property2);
        }

        return args.ToArray();
    }

    private Delegate GetConstructor(object[] arguments)
    {
        var constructors = this.type.GetConstructors();
        foreach (var constructor in constructors)
        {
            var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
            var parameterTypes = parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
            if (parameterTypes.Length != arguments.Length + 1) continue;

            if (!parameterTypes.Zip(arguments, TestArgumentForParameter).All(x => x))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var parameterExpressions = parameters.Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name)).ToArray();
            var callConstructor = Expression.New(constructor, parameterExpressions);
            var ctor = Expression.Lambda(callConstructor, parameterExpressions).Compile();

            ClassConstructors.TryAdd(this.type, ctor);
            return ctor;
        }

        throw new MissingMethodException("No constructor found");
    }

    private static bool TestArgumentForParameter(Type parameterType, object argument)
    {
        return (argument == null && !parameterType.IsValueType) || (parameterType.IsInstanceOfType(argument));
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Am I going about this the right way? I know DynamicInvoke is slow. Should I be going about this differently?

Comment: Take a step back and consider whether your domain model is appropriate. Having a property on a base class that isn't a required property of all derived classes is a code smell. A re-design here may simplify your dependency injection requirements.

Comment: Consider a base class called AccountBase with two properties PrimaryAccountHolder and SecondaryAccountHolder. Now let's say there are 100 different account types which are modeled as derived classes to AccountBase. Every single type of account CAN have both a primary and a secondary account holder. However, there are specific types of accounts such as JointAccount that REQUIRES a secondary account holder. You don't know which type of account object to create until run-time. How would you model that any differently?

Comment: Separate accounts and account holders. Model Account and Customer as distinct entitles. Model the AccountHolder as a separate entity simply linking a Customer to an Account. Admittedly, this probably doesn't help with your DI question.